# custom button drawable error

Tags: android, drawable, xml-drawable

I was following [Custom Buttons](http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=56) to create custom buttons with different style.

In that link they have said to add Android.jar.

I hope when i create project itself it will be added (am i right?)

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with
>   value '@android:drawable/  grey_button_background_pressed_blue').

But i'm getting above error. When i followed that tutorial.

Wat error this could be?

Comment: one of the comments in the link you posted says "Please edit mybutton_background.xml in the drawable folder. Patch four items. android:drawable=@android:drawable/.... -> android:drawable=@drawable/...."

Comment: Sorry aleph_null that also doesnt work.. Is there any way to solve

Comment: Check your drawable foder, is there mybutton_background.xml in the drawable folder?

Comment: ya drawable/mybutton_background.xml its there

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what version of the SDK's jar did you use? That tutorial seems *reeeeally* old. I just checked my 2.3 SDK folder and there's no "grey" (or blue!) button drawables. Second, most widget images are not publicly exposed, so you wouldn't be able to do what you wanted to do anyway. In general, they way to create a custom button would be to go into the `res` folder of the platform folder in the SDK location (e.g. `\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\data\res\`) and copy over the assets that you want to modify into *your* drawables folder and customize them there.

In this case, you want to copy `\drawable\btn_default.xml` and all of the corresponding images, in `\drawable-hdpi\btn_default_*.png` and update them as you wish. Then to reference the copied button you would use the normal syntax: `@drawable/btn_default` (or whatever name you give it).

Comment: Thanks dmon.. For this we need to create button styles. Is there any website where we can find custom button images? or if we need to create manually how to do

Comment: No idea where to get custom button images. The easiest way is to just modify them with an image editor (e.g. GIMP). Be careful when modifying them to not modify the 9 patch regions; speaking of 9patch, you should [read](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) about [it](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch).

Comment: ya thanks dmon... i'm will take a look of it..... i need to learn a lot in android seems